# Add service reference in visual studio does not work for windows authenticated WCF service

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, wcf, iis, windows-authentication

I have WCF service hosted on IIS with windows authentication.

When a project (Service Consumer) needs to generate proxy class for this service by using "Add service reference" feature of Visual Studio it gives below error.

[image]

How can i achieve this without enabling Anonymous for the service ?

FYR : All consumers and service are in same windows domain.